# How to Make a Transparent Background for jQuery UI Accordion or Tabs?

Tags: jquery-ui

Does anyone know how to render the background of the jquery ui tabs or accordion controls as transparent?

Comment: If I get the question correct, the following classes can help you
`.ui-state-active` and `.ui-state-default`

Answer (score 6):

Add this to your css file:

```
.ui-accordion-content-active
{
    padding: 0 !important;
    border-style: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image: none;
}
```

You can adjust the padding to whatever fits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Find the correct line in the css and change the background attribute to `transparent`.

Comment: this has got to be the most useless answer ever....its like saying "To paint your house would require you to buy paint"....wow! who would have known?

Answer (score 0):

In CSS you can make use of the `rgba(int, int, int, float)` function to define a color. So, I guess you want something like this:

```
background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
```

Note that the RGB components are in the range `[0, 255]` (which is one byte)  and the alpha channel is in the range `[0,1]`.

Answer (score 0):

in the jqueryui css file's 'Component containers' section, you can find the .ui-widget-content class and set

```css
background: transparent;
```

Note: If you are using overlays, they might get messed up~