# JQuery UI tabs - transparent background

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-ui

I have trouble setting jqueryUI tabs to have transparent background. I took the [basic tabs example](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/) and added the following code, as advised e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21030750/684229), but trying to set transparent background:

```
body { background: #ddddff; }
.ui-tabs, .ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav, .ui-tabs .ui-tabs-panel,
.ui-widget-header .ui-state-default,
.ui-state-active, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-active, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-active
{
        background: transparent;
}
```

The problem is, that there is a surplus line (border-bottom) in the navigation widget of the active   tab:

[image]

I also tried to set the `background-image: none` as advised [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11989436/684229), but it doesn't help.

I have jquery-ui 1.10.3, tested on theme "smoothnes".

Comment: put an example on JSFiddle

Comment: you can easily take the basic tabs example I linked and add the code I have in my question..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it! Just change `transparent` to `inherit`! This is a trick!

```
.ui-tabs, .ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav, .ui-tabs .ui-tabs-panel,
.ui-widget-header .ui-state-default,
.ui-state-active, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-active, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-active
{
        background: inherit;
}
```

It's just enough to place it to the following elements:

```
.ui-tabs,
.ui-widget-header,
.ui-widget-header .ui-state-default,
.ui-widget-header .ui-state-active
{
        background: inherit;
}
```

The question is - isn't it dirty? Is it cross-browser safe?

Answer (score 1):

That border you see is the one from the `ul` element with this class `.ui-widget-header`. Is used to give a visual effect of the active tab that hides the border with his background and  the properties:

```
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-tabs-active {
  margin-bottom: -1px;
  padding-bottom: 1px;
}
```

Since your active tab has not background anymore then can't hide the border.

Comment: @Tomas Yep your solution is still need a background at some moment. Whn you inherit you get the bg of the ul widget-header then you can hide the border and of course isn't transparent

Comment: As I said to keep that visual effect you may need the bg

Comment: I explain with my answer why you need to keep a background to keep the visual of tab selected @Tomas

Answer (score 0):

try `background: rgba(0,0,0,0);` and see if that makes any difference?

Can you set up a fiddle?

Comment: The background is fine the problem is the border

Comment: OP says "I have trouble setting jqueryUI tabs to have transparent background."

Answer (score 0):

Simple.  Add the following class right after your posted CSS:

```
.ui-widget-header {
    border-bottom:0;
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

The above code will remove the entire border-bottom of the navigation, which is not what we wanted.  jQuery uses the active tab's class background to overlay (or hide) the border underneath it, giving the effect that it meshes with the content below it.

Since our backgrounds here are set to `transparent`, I don't think it's possible to hide the bottom border with how jQuery UI constructs these tabs.  Instead, we're presented with a bare wireframe.

I suggest coming up with an alternative way to show tabbed content than using jQuery UI's library.

Comment: Did you test it? This will remove the *whole* horizontal line for sure.

Comment: Whoops, misunderstood the "active tab" part of your comment.  Will update shortly.